# scp remoteA:file remoteB:

Tags: ssh, scp

with scp I can get a file

```
 scp remoteA:file .
```

and put a file

```
 scp file remoteB:
```

but when I try

```
 scp remoteA:file remoteB:
```

I get

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname remoteB: Name or service not known
lost connection
```

why?

#### EDIT:

the remoteA and remoteB description is in ~/.ssh/config

Comment: Using `scp` to copy between two remote hosts works perfectly fine for me. Are you sure you haven't made a typo in your command (like you have made in your question title)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

likely not related to scp itself, but some sort of name resolution from one host to another. another thing to consider is authentication. it is best you have a passphrase-less key auth from A to B. in which host's .ssh/config you are defining these hosts? scp is not finding that definition. try the real fqdn of the host and it should work fine, if host definition is the problem. also, use -v to see if more details can be found for the error.

Comment: If you're able to ssh into remoteA, can you connect from remoteA to remoteB?

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify a host which `remoteA` can reach because the copy is made from `remoteA` directly to `remoteB`.

To avoid this you can use the `-3` option. `man scp` says what it does:

> Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the local host.  Without this option the data is copied directly between the two remote hosts.  Note that this option disables the progress meter.

Comment: It can be argued whether this should be a default or not, I certainly did expect it to be, otherwise I'd just `ssh` into `remoteA` and do a normal `scp` while enjoying that sweet path auto-completion. Anyway this answer saved my sanity, so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For those who come here because scp accuses a local file of being a hostname which it can't resolve (another source of *Name or service not known*), such as:

```
> scp archive_2017-03-01-09:54:02.tar.gz backupserver:/var/backups/
ssh: Could not resolve hostname archive_2017-03-01-09:54:02.tar.gz: Name or service not known
```

Workaround:

```
> scp ./archive_2017-03-01-09:54:02.tar.gz backupserver:/var/backups/
```